# print blank in Web scraping

Tags: python, scrapy

Lets say i have the following script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class StrongSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Strong'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.strongflex.de/en/4-acura-integra-93-01/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.strongflex.de/en/4-acura-integra-93-01/']

def parse(self,response):
    product_container = response.css("div.product-container")
    prodname = product_container.css("a.product-name::text").extract_first().strip()
    price = product_container.css("span.price::text").extract_first().strip()
    description = product_container.css("p.product-desc::text").extract_first().strip()
    img = product_container.css("img.replace-2x.img-responsive::attr(src)").extract_first()

    for item in zip(prodname,price,description,img):
        scraped_info = {
        'prodname' : prodname[0],
        'price' : price[1],
        'description' : description[2],
        'img' : img[3],
    }
        yield scraped_info
```

and I wanted to say in looping system if does not exist item[1] then print blank, actually i don't know how to do that...and my script just skiping if all the product does not have price

Comment: Why are you incrementing the indices? For example, why are you setting `'price': price[1]` instead of `'price': price[0]` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send item with empty value instead of skipping, you can do it like this

```
for item in zip(prodname,price,description,img):
    scraped_info = {
        'prodname' : prodname[0],
        'price' : price[1] if len(price)>=2 else '',
        'description' : description[2],
        'img' : img[3],
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not usual to take extract_first() and do only single page requests. may be you better post more of spider code? Ok, more important thing 
could you show debug print of _scraped_info_ ? The output do not make big sense

`{'description': 'f', 'img': 'r', 'price': '0', 'prodname': '0'}`

rather you've stop truncate items with [indexes] and you'v got 
`{'description': 'ref: 081097B\r\nMaterial: POLYURETHANE (PUR/PU)\r\nHardness 80ShA\r\nPcs/prod: 1\r\nRequired/car: 2\r\nTo every product we add grease!',
 'img': 'acura-integra-93-01_files/front-anti-roll-bar-bush.jpg',
 'price': '10,01 €',
 'prodname': '081097B: Front anti roll bar bush'}`

so, this way

`scraped_info = {
 'prodname' : prodname,
 'price' : price,
 'description' : description,
 'img' : img,
 }`

NotaBene: the problem  seems to be a test task from employer, isn't it?  If it is the case sorry for late answer. good luck!